# Поиск по порядковому номеру

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с записями `Н` штук. Сортированы по `ИД`. Надо чтобы из отрывка порядкового номера от `А` до `Б` выбрать 10 штук записей.

Например допустим у нас 10000 записей. Сортированы по `ИД`, надо выбрать 10 штук записей от отрывка 584-1000.

```
select * from rows where id in (select id from rows where 1 order by id desc limit 584, 1000) order by rand() limit 10
```

приблизительно такой код.

Какие есть варианты?

Comment: `select * from rows where id BETWEEN 584 and 1000 order by id desc limit 10` ?

Comment: нет не по ИД, а по порядковому номеру.

Comment: делаете ваш подзапрос через inner join, а присоединяете по условию `using(id)`, тогда должно сработать. Т.е. условие `where id in(...)` вообще выпиливаете (т.к. оно теперь в конструкции `using` есть). Как-то так: `select * from rows inner join (select id from rows where order by id desc limit 584, 1000) as limit_subquery using(id) limit 10`. Только ответ не забудьте написать ))

Comment: блин, опечатку у себя поздно заметил - в подзапросе не надо писать `..from rows where order...`, вместо этого должно быть `...from rows order...`, иначе будет ошибка на не валидную конструкцию

Comment: Спасибо большое) Да опечатку сам заметил и исправил) все работает! Отлично!

Comment: Ответ не забудьте написать, а то я вас запомню и ночью снится буду ))) а так еще и плюсы можете получить )

Comment: а вот так не то же самое? `select * from (select * from rows order by id desc limit 584, 1000) t order by rand() limit 10`

Comment: @splash58, по-хорошему, не должно, т.к. в моем варианте выборка и сортировка только по id идет, а значит будет задействован только индекс, в то время как в вашем варианте придется еще и данные с диска читать (+ пересылать их все из подзапроса наружу). Но план выполнения для этих запросов почему-то все равно одинаковый... Хотя справедливости ради стоит заметить, что реальное время выполнения на моем запросе меньше, чем на вашем именно из-за меньшего времени на пересылку данных из внутреннего подзапроса. Но если данных будет мало и время выполнения устраивает, то можно и ваш способ использовать

Comment: @BOPOH а mysql не оптимизирует такие случаи - те на всякий подзапрос обязательно таблица строится, я правильно вас понимаю?

Comment: @splash58, вам лучше задать отдельный вопрос, т.к. он может быть интересен и остальным, но здесь, в дебрях комментариев, он затеряется. Про оптимизацию не понял - какие случаи? Про таблицу точно не уверен, но вроде как всегда временная создается, а значит и скопировать в нее надо все перечисленные в запросе поля, а потом их еще и клиенту вернуть. Т.е. данные два раза пересылаются. Если только id указать - для подзапроса только id летит + не надо лишний раз диск читать (вместо 500 чтений будет всего 10). Хотя по плану выполнения - подзапрос плохо оптимизируется, для моего запроса мог лучше быть

Comment: какие случаи? = я имею в виду, что отбираемые данные ни в каких условиях дальше не участвуют. поэтому можно отбирать до последнего иоиента только первичный ключ таблиц. Но это исключительно домыслы :) А на насчет отдельного вопроса, боюсь у менчя мозгов не хватит его хорошо сформулировать :)

Comment: @splash58, ну так они же участвуют - они дальше передаются и отдаются пользователю. Если бы отдавался только id, то еще можно было бы что-то съоптимизировать, хотя не уверен что такое предусмотрено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо ВОРОН! Все работает!
Хотел плюсовать коммент, не получилось сори)

```
select * from rows inner join (select id from rows where order by id desc limit 584, 1000) as limit_subquery using(id) limit 10
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, Вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтете полезными. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/56148)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну здесь "спасибо" с ответом. Т.е. если удалить текст, либо заменить на "решил так:", то уже можно считать ответом. В идеале было бы не плохо расписать почему именно так было сделано и чем это лучше, например, того же [варианта @splash58](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485019/#comment563183_485019), но мне лень комменты в ответ переносить )

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
   select rows.*,@N:=@N+1 as N
     from rows,(select @N:=0) A
    where @N<=1000
    order by id desc
) A
where N>=584
order by rand()
limit 10
```

По скорости работы не сильно хуже вашего изначального варианта, потому как при задании в `limit` диапазона mySql все равно пробегается по всем записям до 584, что бы понять с какого места собственно начинать.

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю убрать второй лимит и внести его во внутренний запрос. Вы получаете упорядоченный набор из `1000-584` id, из которых вам нужно только 10.

Конструкция IN в конечном итоге раскрывается в следующее условие `... id=id1 OR id=id2 OR ...`. По плану итоговая выборка будет также достаточно упорядочена.

Если взять только первые 10 id начиная с 584, то условие в вопросе будет полностью выполнено.

`select * from rows where id in (select id from rows where 1 order by id desc limit 584, 594)`

Comment: *и внести его во внутренний запрос* - а вы это проверяли? mysql это позволяет? У меня (и у автора) не работает, иначе бы и limit снаружи бы сработал

Comment: у меня так не работает (

Comment: @FəqanÇələbizadə, посмотрите мой коммент к вопросу - так должно работать даже с вашим последним редактированием вопроса